# Textfield not showing

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I want to show a textfield on an image. To do so, I used a ZStack view.
But the textfield isn't showing up.

Here is my code :

```
var meme: some View {
        ZStack {
            image!
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            TextField("Enter here", text: $topText)
                .padding(.all)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
```

Why is it doing this ?

Answer (score 4):

The `TextField` is there, but just difficult to see. You can add a background color to it, similar to what it would look like in something like Snapchat. You will now be able to see it and know where to tap.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var topText = ""

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()

            TextField("Enter here", text: $topText)
                .padding(.all)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]